# Remove Infopath form from external list?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, external-content-type

The InfoPath form has broken for the external list. How to remove all GUI InfoPath form from the external list? I want to rebuild the InfoPath again for the external list without having to recreate a new List & Form for a BCS - external list.

I have tried to remove the three form two InfoPath forms (displayif.aspx) and (editfs.aspx), but I was unable to recreate and publish the form.

Answer (score 0):

No Need to remove the displayif.aspx and editfs.aspx. Just go to the list where you have created the form and go to **list settings** -> under **General settings** -> **Form Settings** ->select use default SharePoint form and you can find delete the InfoPath form from the server and delete the existing infopaht form.create new form and add to the list back. 
[image]
Let me know if it worked.

Try this

1. Choose Site Actions, Edit in SharePoint Designer to modify the current site in SharePoint Designer 2010.
2. Click External Content Types from the left hand navigation pane in SharePoint Designer.
3. Click the External Content Type for the External List that you want to modify.
4. Click the Create Lists and Forms command on the ribbon.
5. A dialog box will display asking if you would like to replace the InfoPath form for the selected External List or create a new External List.  In my example I am going to replace the InfoPath form for the External List as shown below. Click Ok.
6. Click External Lists from the left hand navigation pane.
7. Click the External List you just created or modified.
8. Click the Design Forms in InfoPath command on the ribbon.
9. The Form will display in InfoPath.
10. Choose the Page Design ribbon and select a page design and add rules and stuff whatever you need to be done on the form.
11. Publish the form to the list by clicking File, and then Publish, and then External List.

Comment: It did not work in the BCS - ECT List. The error was "
InfoPath does not support customizing the form used for this list. "

Comment: Please check the edited answer

Comment: Will it work on SharePoint Designer 2013? I will try, please let me know.

Comment: I don't think there is change in 2013 with regards this you can follow this.